# prblem in accessing a Java servlet from PHP Script

Tags: java, php, servlets

I am trying to invoke a Java servlet from PHP. When I access the servlet from a browser I always get the results. But when I access it from a pHP script. I am not getting the results properly. Sometimes I dont get the results at all.

Comment: Please post that **servlet** url and php script here.

Answer (score 1):

If servelt's get method is implemented then you may request a `Servlet url` in PHP code by setting `href` of `anchor` tag or set `action` attribute of `form` tag.

1. `<a href="http://example.com/myservlet">Test</a>`
2. `<form method='GET' action='http://example.com/myservlet'>`

If `POST` method is implemented in servlet class then use `form` tag. Set `method='POST'` and `action='http://example.com/myservlet'`.

Comment: I understood that the OP is trying to access it by `curl` or something.